# UITextfield inside dynamic/dequeuable UITableviewcells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uitextfield

I have this tableview with enough cells to need scrolling,each cell is a custom cell that contains a label and a UITextField. I´m attempting [this](http://behindtechlines.com/2012/06/ios-tip-uitextfield-inside-dynamic-prototype-dequeuable-uitableviewcells/) solution

When I enter text in the textfield and I scroll the tableview to see other cells,my text written from before disappears,leaving a blank textfield.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYq8FPtp09I) is the problem im having

My code for cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Mycell";
MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


// Configure the cell...

cell.myLabel.text = [labelarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.myTextbox.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.myTextbox.text = stringVariable;



return cell;
}
```

stringVariable is declared in the .h

```
 interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>{

NSMutableArray *labelarray ;
NSString *stringVariable;
__weak IBOutlet UITableView *myTableview;
}
```

And i initialized it here:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    MyTableViewCell *cell;
    stringVariable = [[NSString alloc]init];
    if (textField == cell.myTextbox) {
        self->stringVariable = cell.myTextbox.text;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the cells go out of the screen, they are destroyed, and will be recreated when they will appear again.

To preserve the data entered, you will need to store it using the `UITextField` delegate method `textFieldDidEndEditing:`.

What you did in that method is wrong. To begin, you are not your cell object is not pointing anywhere, it is always `nil`. Secondly, you can't have a single variable (`stringVariable`) to store all the data, you need an array, so each element will correspond to one text field.

Add the property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *textFieldData;
```

Then allocate it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    self.textFieldData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:<number of rows>];
    // ...
}
```

Then the delegate:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.textFieldData[[textField tag]] = textField.text;
}
```

For each `UITextField` you have, don't forget to set your controller as the delegate.

Finally, when you recreating the cell, use:

```
cell.myTextbox = self.textFieldData[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I have done all of what you have described is there anything else i must do? Because the app doesn't even load and crashes when starting.